# Is it better to reuse or recreate a reactive source in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a template called 'contacts'.  Inside is an #each which renders the template 'contact'.  The user can press the 'edit' button which sets a session variable with the mongo id of the edited row.  The row then reactively re-renders into "edit" mode.

```
Template.contact.viewEditing = function() {
    return Session.get("contactViewEditingId") === this._id;
}
```

The html uses the viewEditing helper a few times, for instance:

```
{{#if viewEditing}}
<div class="panel-heading">EDITING!</div>
{{/if}}
```

I need to bind some javascript in the .rendered().  I would like to check again if we are editing.  I can think of 2 options:

1. Should I call Template.content.viewEditing() inside my template.rendered() ?  Does this save on reactivity calculations?
2. Or should I just copy pasta the if statement.  This option seems to violate DRY.

Option 1:

```
Template.contact.rendered = function() {
    if( Template.contact.viewEditing.call(this.data) ) {
        // Bind some fancy jQuery
        bindEditInPlace(this.data);
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
Template.contact.rendered = function() {
    if( Session.get("contactViewEditingId") === this._id ) {
        // Bind some fancy jQuery
        bindEditInPlace(this.data);
    }
}
```

I think that putting {{viewEditing}} multiple times in your template doesn't "cost" anything extra.  So logically I would think that using this helper elsewhere is better. Maybe I need more help understanding reactivity calculations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are run inside a Deps.Computation, which means that every time a reactive variable is referenced and modified in a helper, it will re-run.

Template.rendered is a callback that runs each time the template is re-rendered (which usually happens when a helper in the template is re-run reactively), but it is not itself a reactive computation.

So it doesn't matter using either the template helper or copy-pasting its code inside your rendered callback : both ways won't trigger a reactive computation invalidation because we are not inside one.

As far as DRY is concerned, you could refactor your code like this :

```
function isContactViewEditing(contactView){
    return Session.equals("contactViewEditingId",contactView._id);
}

Template.contact.helpers({
    viewEditing:isContactViewEditing
});

Template.contact.rendered=function(){
    if(isContactViewEditing(this.data)){
        //
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think saimeunt's answer is correct, especially if you have more complex logic in the function which you don't want to replicate.

Create a local function which you can re-use in both the helper and the .rendered callback.

If you had a case where you wanted to use a reactive source minus the reactivity you could make it non-reactive by wrapping it in a Deps.nonreactive function likes so:

```
Deps.nonreactive(function(){
   //Reactive stuff here
});
```

Regarding reactivity concerns, pay attention to his change from using Session.get to Session.equals. Session.get will cause any reactive computation it is used in to re-calculate on every change of the session variable. So if you use this helper in multiple places with different ids, and you change the session variable, every single one will re-calculate and re-render the templates they are used in. Session.equals only invalidates a computation when the equality changes. So changing the session variable from one non-equal id to another non-equal id will not cause the computation/template to re-run when you use Session.equals.

For your specific example where the helper is only returning the result of a Session.equals you might consider creating a global handlebars helper that can do this for you with any session variable and any value. Like the following.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('sessionEquals', function (key, value) {
    return Session.equals(key, value);
});
```

Then in the template use it like so:

```
{{#if sessionEquals 'contactViewEditingId' _id}}
    <div class="panel-heading">EDITING!</div>
{{/if}}
```

In the template when rendering an item that is editable add a unique class name to mark the item as editable. Then in your Template.rendered callback when binding the javascript use a selector which looks for that class and only binds to elements with that special class.

Comment: I like your idea of registering a handlebars helper, however I don't like pasting the long string inside my template.  I wish I could accept your answer bro!